# Rotate PDF pages in different directions

Tags: pdf-reader

My three PDF readers

- Soda
- Foxit
- Adobe

can't rotate a pdf page: I want to rotate page1 to the left and page2 to the right. I can only rotate all pages in the same direction.

Comment: Are you concerned with viewing or printing?

Comment: I want to view it correctly.

Comment: Well darn if you ain't right.  I tried it with Okular and got the same thing.  It looks like some programs are just more robust than others.  If your Adobe is just the free reader, that is more limited than the full product, which I think can do it page by page.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen many **free tools** that lets you **rotate single pages** within a PDF document, however one example would be [**PDF Arranger**](https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger/releases), an open-source software available on GitHub.

PDF Arranger has limited functions but is straightforward and simple

[image]

Similar applications can be found on this webpage: [AlternativeTo](https://alternativeto.net/software/pdf-arranger/?license=free)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Finally met a problem I can help with!

This is a problem that very few people pay attention to, but it's really often to run into (at least in my experience). If I think back, I often found that after scanning a booklet with my phone, each page was facing a different direction.

[This PDF software](https://www.pdfgear.com) I'm using allows me to select each page of the PDF separately and rotate them one by one in different directions (only with the desktop version).

It also has an online version, which unfortunately is not able to rotate each page in different directions.

Before rotation↓

[image: before rotation]

After rotation↓

[image: after rotation]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a Canon MX930 series printer that came with a software feature called **My Image Garden** that until today I found useless and irritating. Today I was able to use it to rotate individual pages of multi page PDF files.

The process is:

1. Navigate to the desired directory on the left part of the window.
   The PDF file thumbnails appear in the main part of the window.
2. Select Tools > Preferences, select "Display file name below thumbnails" and click OK if desired.
3. Click on the thumbnail for the file to edit.
4. Click on "Create/Edit PDF File" at the bottom of the window.
   Thumbnail views of the individual pages are displayed in the main window.
5. Click on the thumbnail of the page to edit.
   Editing options are displayed at the bottom of the window.
6. Click on the desired action to perform.
7. Click Edit > Select All at the top.
   7, Click Save at the bottom.

A Save dialogue box will open.

If Select All is not clicked then only the selected page is saved.

Comment: Not so useful to the OP or others who don't have a canon printer.